# Código PHP não executa e retorna como comentario pra o HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho um código em `javascript` chamando um arquivo `PHP`:

```js
$.post("subscript.php", {
  idPost: idPost
}, function(response2) {
  //Joga o resultado no lugar desejado.
  $("#respostaID").html(response2);
});
```

Quando esse código responde, ao invés de trazer a resposta do `PHP` que foi executado, ele me devolve o código do arquivo subscript.php comentado dentro do `HTML` da página mãe.

Código `PHP`:

```
    <?php 

      $idPost = $_POST['idPost'];

      echo "<h1>".$idPost."</h1>";
    ?>
```

Resposta que eu tenho após a resposta do `javascript`:

```html
<div id="respostaID" class="btn-group btn-group-justified pull-right"><!--?php 

  $idPost = $_POST['idPost'];

echo "<h1-->".$idPost."";

   
?></div>
```

Como fazer com que meu arquivo em `PHP` execute e me traga somente o que eu preciso?

Ambos os arquivos estão no formato `.php`

OBS: Esses códigos estão sendo implementados junto de um tema no wordpress.

Comment: O PHP funciona sem ser via ajax? ou seja, consegues processar PHP?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no servidor, ele não está processando o PHP

Comment: Bom galera, essa é uma gambiarra que estou fazendo dentro de um wordpress. O php ta normal porque estou executando o wordpress.

Answer (score -1):

A tag `<?php` precisa estar bem no início da linha, não pode ter tab:

```
<?php 

  $idPost = $_POST['idPost'];

  echo "<h1>".$idPost."</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: O código está com a indentação correta no arquivo.

Comment: Leo, qual é a diferença de ter o `<?php` no inicio ou não?

Comment: precisa estar no início da linha para ser interpretado como script

Comment: O lugar da tag `<?php` não faz diferença nesse caso. Se fosse assim, PHP não funcionaria no meio de código HTML.